# Number of strings consisting of k ones and n zeros such that no two ones are adjacent

Tags: combinatorics

What is number of strings consisting of k ones and n zeros such that no two ones are adjacent?

I already know the answer from wikipedia $\binom{n+1}{k}$ but i want to know its source.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Write down the $n$ $0$'s in a row, with a little gap between them, like this:
$$0\quad0\quad0\quad0\quad0\quad0\quad0\quad0\quad0\quad0\quad0\quad0\quad0\quad0\quad0\quad0\quad0\quad0$$

This determines $n+1$ "gaps," $n-1$ of them real gaps between consecutive $0$'s, and the two "endgaps." We must **choose** $k$ of these to slip a $1$ into.

**Remark:** This also works if say $n=5$ and $k=8$, if we use the convention that for non-negative integers $a$ and $b$, we have $\binom{a}{b}=0$ if $a\lt b$.

Comment: Great Answer! $  $

Comment: Oh it was that simple. Thank you mean u really helped me out :) I will accept answer afer 6 minutes.